# How to handle exceptions thrown in Isolates?

Tags: multithreading, dart, error-handling, dart-isolates

I'm experimenting with Dart and using the new [`streamSpawnFunction`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate.html#streamSpawnFunction) to create a new isolate.

I'm running my code in Dartium but i've noticed that if some kind of unrecoverable error occurs in the isolate i get no error message on the console. Because breakpoints in Isolate code are not working debugging is really painful.

The old Port based Isolate spawn function ([`spawnFunction`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_isolate.html#spawnFunction)) has a callback function for handling errors. I wonder why this is not available with `streamSpawnFunction`. Is there a new way to subscribe to the error events of an Isolate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The missing functionality of streamSpawnFunction is just an oversight. I filed http://dartbug.com/9208 and I will try to fix it next week.

I'm not sure if it is a known problem that breakpoints don't work in isolates. I will let you file a bug-report (http://dartbug.com) so the devs can ask you questions and you are kept informed on the process.

Comment: Thank you, starred the issue.
I've searched the net about the breakpoints not working in isolates bug and it seems that others had trouble with this aswell: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/misc/X5xba5QVQig
I'm using the latest non bleeding edge 64bit build on my Win8 box. Non isolate breakpoints are working. I've tried putting a minimal sample into my index.dart file but still no luck. I'll file a bug then.

Comment: Don't forget we still need exception handler for spawnUri()/spawnStreamUri() while you're at it. :)

https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=8454